# Changing the order of columns displayed with `ls`

Tags: bash, ls, dir

Is it possible to change the order of displayed columns when running `ls -l` on *nix (or `dir` on Windows)?

For example, I'd like to see the date modified, then the name, then other fields (or select only the ones I want, and their order.

How would this be done without *merely* using `cut` and trimming undesired fields (since that does not address the issue of re-ordering)?

Comment: as a note regarding cut, you'd get more milage out of awk in this case. ls -al | awk '{print $3 " " $1}'

Answer (score 4):

I'd avoid parsing `ls` at all: use [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) and `sort`:

```
stat --printf="%y\t%n\t%F\t%s\n" * | sort -t $'\t' -k 2
```

is a start.

Comment: and what would be the equivalent for mac ? On mac I am getting `stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]`

Comment: What does the man page say?

Comment: this https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z2xzg-3pq25bRmbT8-O0-v6GtezTxLG8iB8BTzsZdVw/edit?usp=sharing